# Kinect Background Removal and Particle dynamics using opengl?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, kinect-sdk

I'm making an application with KINECT SDK 1.8, OpenGL and DirectShow.

My objective is to extract the human with KINECT background removal API and add avi video's frame as a background using DirectShow's IVMR9WindowlessControl9:GetCurrentImage. Then draw about 1000 square textures which have some transparency to make a fire(particle dynamics).

I add video background if the extracted image's pixel's alpha is 0. If the pixel's alpha is 0, I add video frame's pixel in there.

When KINECT didn't detect human, and video frame's pixel fills the background, the fire comes out very well.

The problem is this : When KINECT detected human, and video frame's pixel fills the background except the human area, the fire comes out, but there are few particles consisting fire, and sometimes, the other particles which weren't showed up when the human was detect showed up and then disappear in a moment.
After the KINECT couldn't detect the human, the hidden particles just show up and it runs very well.